# Limit without applying l'hopital's rule, $\lim_{x \rightarrow-\infty} \frac{|2x+5|}{2x+5}$.

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity, limits-without-lhopital

This is the question:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow-\infty} \frac{|2x+5|}{2x+5}$$

I know the answer is $-1$, but can someone go through the steps and explaining it to me?

Comment: Note that if $2x+5\lt 0$, then $|2x+5|=-(2x+5).$

Comment: @mathlove Thank you for answering, but please correct me here: If you evaluated the piecewise function, wouldn't it be -(2x+5) where x < -5/2 instead of < 0? So since it's as x tends to negative infinity, what would happen if it is -1/2 vs -9/2? Thank you for correcting my format btw. New User.

Comment: Kindly note that here, $x$ is tending to $- \infty$. that means, $2x + 5$ also tends to $-\infty$. So, by definition, |2x + 5| will be equal to -(2x+5)

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali Thank you for clarifying a little bit. Do you mind elaborating more on "Kindly note that here, x is tending to −∞. that means, 2x+5 also tends to −∞"? How is x the same as 2x+5?

Comment: Whenever I come up with these problems, I generally follow this: $x \to 1 \implies 2x \to 2 \implies 2x + 5 \implies 6 $ ... Similarly, for $ x \to - \infty \implies 2x \to -\infty \implies 2x + 5\to -\infty$

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali Thank you for answering but I'm still having trouble understanding it. Do you mind simplifying the explanation a little bit more? Also to go back to the previous question, how is x the same as 2x+5?

Comment: Okay, suppose, value of $x$ is in fact tending to $\infty$ . What do you think about $2x$ then? Where will it tend to? $\infty$ , right?

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali Yep.

Comment: What do you think about $2x+5$ then?

Comment: Shouldn't it also tend to $\infty$ ?

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali Yes.

Comment: Now, try the same for $x \to -\infty$ ... What will $2x$ tend to? What will $2x+5$ tend to?

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali They will both tend to -∞

Comment: Excellent! So, that's what I'm trying to explain. As $x \to -\infty$ , then $2x + 5 \to -\infty$ which in fact concludes, $2x + 5 < 0 $ ... Got it?

Comment: AHA! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: You're welcome, @user235952 ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should better be aware of the definition of a modulus function.

$$|x| = \left\{\begin{matrix}
x &  x > 0\\ 
0 & x = 0 \\ 
-x  & x<0 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

For this question,

$$|2x+5| = \left\{\begin{matrix}
2x+5 &  2x+5 > 0\\ 
0 & 2x+5 = 0 \\ 
-(2x+5)  & 2x+5<0 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Here, since, $x \to -\infty$ , that is $2x + 5 <0 $ , so, $|2x+5| = -(2x+5)$ and you get the limit as $-1$.

To **answer your question** in specific that what will be its limit when $x$ tends to $-9/2$ or $-1/2$ . Well, here is the difference.

$x \to -1/2 \implies 2x \to -1 \implies 2x + 5 \to 4 $ ($2x+4 >0$ )

So, $\lim_{x \to -1/2} \cfrac{|2x+5|}{2x + 5} = 1 $

While for $x\to -9/2 \implies 2x \to -9 \implies 2x + 5\to -4 $ ($2x+5 <0$)

So, $\lim_{x \to -9/2} \cfrac{|2x+5|}{2x +5} = - 1$

Answer (score 1):

If you're confused by the function, hust set $2x+5 = t$, and you just have $\lim_{t \to - \infty} \frac{|t|}{t}$. Can you handle from here?

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but my concern is before the limits, where I need to sort the equation. My question is when you seperate it to a piecewise function. Wouldn't the range of (2x+5)/(2x+5) be when x > -5/2 and -(2x+5)/(2x+5) be when x < -5/2? So when the limit is as x tends to negative infinity, wouldn't x = -1/2 and x = -9/2 all be part of negative infinity?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The fact that there's a problem at $x= -\frac{5}{2}$ has nothing to do with what happens when $x \to -\infty$, because the question is about the limit, not continuity

Answer (score 1):

The limits at infinity of a rational function is the limit of the ratio of the terms of highest degree.

Alternatively, with *equivalents:*

$2x+5\sim_{\pm\infty}2x$, $\,\lvert2x+5\rvert\sim_{-\infty}-2x$, hence
$$\frac{\lvert2x+5\rvert}{2x+5}\sim_{-\infty}\frac{-2x}{2x}=-1.$$

Answer (score 0):

In $(-\infty,0)$ the function is identically the constant $-1$. The limit of a constant is this constant.